# Making two widgets on one page in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I need to add two widgets together in one page like this :

```
getPageR :: Handler Html
getPageR = defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Titre de la page"
    $(widgetFile "rightzone" ++ "leftzone")
```

but this gives me a error.

Comment: Can you please include the error message, and what issued the error (for example: the compiler, tests that come with yesod, the yesod runtime)? I suspect it is an error from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use yesod, but a quick [Hayoo!](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) suggests that the type of `widgetFile` is `String -> Q Exp`. That's a Template Haskell expression. I'm guessing your error is that you can't apply the `++` operator to a `Q Exp` from `widgetFile "rightzone"` and a `String` from `"leftzone"`.

`defaultLayout` is `WidgetT site IO () -> HandlerT site IO Html`, so `$(widgetFile ...)` should be a Template Haskell expression for something of type `WidgetT site IO ()`. So, to combine two widgets, you are probably looking for a function with a type like `WidgetT site IO () -> WidgetT site IO () -> WidgetT site IO ()`. `WidgetT` has a `Monad` instance `Monad m => Monad (WidgetT site m)`, so `Monad`'s `>>` operator should have the right type to combine two widgets together. If your two widgets are "rightzone" and "leftzone", you probably want to do something like `$(widgetFile "rightzone") >> $(widgetFile "leftZone")`. You can probably write this as

```
getPageR :: Handler Html
getPageR = defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Titre de la page"
        $(widgetFile "rightzone") >> $(widgetFile "leftzone")
```

or as

```
getPageR :: Handler Html
getPageR = defaultLayout $ do
        aDomId <- newIdent
        setTitle "Titre de la page"
        $(widgetFile "rightzone")
        $(widgetFile "leftzone")
```

I have no idea what `>>` means for widgets, but it should have the right type to be able to try it and find out.